# Accessing the parent Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop

I know that the title might seem silly, couldn't think of something better, sorry.

I have 2 Forms (C#), the main-form holds an instance of the second.
Is there a way to.. get access to the running instance of Form1 (The entry point) and to his properties from the instance of form2?

Everybody tells me to learn OOP.
I did, a long long time ago, and I still don"t get it.

Comment: Either you learned OOP so long ago that you've forgotten, or you didn't learn as much as you think you did. Your original title is the best evidence of that fact. If you really understood OOP, the idea of one class messing with another's internals should probably make your skin crawl. The right way to do this is passing parameters and making calls to public methods.

Comment: @Cody, Messing with class internals wasn't what I meant, I am very aware of the need for encapsulation. I just wanted access to the form's properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably instanciated Form2 from within Form1. After instanciating and BEFORE showing it you could set a property on Form2 that refers to Form1 like this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.TheParent = this;
f2.Show();
```

Of course you have to add the TheParent property to the Form2 class to be able to do that.

Warning: although it is possible this way a better solution might be to create a seperate object that holds all required/shared data andd pass that object to each form in a similar way. This will prevent your code from becoming too coupled.

Comment: Thank you :) That's exactly what I needed to know. I mean, I used the Owner property of the form, but it worked.

Comment: @IneedHelp - you are correct, I made the property up and unfortunately it already exists. I'll change my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

When the main form instantiates the second form, it could pass a reference to itself to the constructor of the second form.

Thus, the second form will have access to the public members of the first.

**EDIT**

In the Form1 you instantiate Form2 somewhere and pass it a reference to Form1 in ctor:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
```

In the class definition of Form2 add a field:

```
private Form1 m_form = null;
```

In the constructor of the second form set that field:

```
public Form2(Form1 f)
{
   m_form = f;
}
```

Then, everywhere in your Form2 you have access to Form1 through the means of m_form

Comment: Why not just write `public Form1 m_form;`?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this can be creating an owner-owned relationship.

```
// Create a form and make this form its owner    
Form ownedForm = new Form();
ownedForm.Owner = this;
ownedForm.Show();
```

or as a shortcut, you could pass the owner form as an argument to an overload of the `Show` method, which also takes an IWin32Window parameter

```
ownedForm.Show(this); // established owner-owned relationship
```

Then you could access the main form properties like this

```
((MainForm)this.Owner).ownerVariable;
```

In order for this variable/method to be accessible, it has to have the `internal` protection modifier.